# How do I identify a package by number in a webpack bundle?

Tags: webpack

I have a package that is causing me a problem with React server side rendering, but I don't know what it is. All I know is it has an identifier "58" from webpack. How do I identify the package? These are the first few lines:

```
},{}],58:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (global){
/*! JSON v3.3.2 | http://bestiejs.github.io/json3 | Copyright 2012-2014, Kit Cambridge | http://kit.mit-license.org */
;(function () {
  // Detect the `define` function exposed by asynchronous module loaders. The
  // strict `define` check is necessary for compatibility with `r.js`.
  var isLoader = typeof define === "function" && define.amd;

  // A set of types used to distinguish objects from primitives.
  var objectTypes = {
    "function": true,
    "object": true
  };
```

I think it is possible that json3 is the package, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You have an exact name `/*! JSON v3.3.2 | http://bestiejs.github.io/json3 | Copyright 2012-2014, Kit Cambridge | http://kit.mit-license.org */`

Comment: Ya that's what I thought but this is just luck in this situation. The question is how to identify it by the webpack id. Thanks!